# Jquery search, hide div by id

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm having troubles with the following code.
I'm populating a webpage with some elements from an array:

```
$a = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

foreach($a as $item) {

echo  '<div class="column col-3" id="'.$item.'" >';
}
```

and i have a simple search box:

`<input class="form-input" id="filter" type="text" placeholder="filter">`

It is possible to hide elements by id when user starts input?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#filter").keyup(function() {

each element in webpage
    if div id contains userinput
        keepelement
    else
        hideit
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please share your HTML page and JavaScript code.

Comment: If you have pseudo code, why don't you do some research into converting it to real code instead of just asking us to do your job for you? If you do that and run into some specific issue along the way, we can help with that. But don't just ask us to solve it for you without showing any type of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code. You'd better use keyup function.

In keypress event on #filter div, it iterates div with .column class and checks if its id contains a value of filter div. If it contains, it will be hidden and others will be shown.

```
<input class="form-input" id="filter" type="text" placeholder="filter"/>
<?php
$a = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

foreach ($a as $item) {
    echo '<div class="column col-3" id="' . $item . '" >' . $item . '</div>';
}
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#filter").keypress(function (e) {
            const val = e.target.value;
            $('div.column').each(function (ind, ele) {
                if (ele.id.includes(val)) {
                    $(ele).hide();
                } else {
                    $(ele).show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does it do? How does it work? A good answer includes a proper and detailed explanation, not just a chunk of code. And imho, the OP should show some effort before we answer, or SO will just be a free coding service.

Comment: why not  use input?  i.e $('#filter').input(function() it seems better than keypress

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filter').keyup(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        var str = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase();
        if(str.indexOf($('#filter').val().toLowerCase())){
            $(this).removeClass('d-none');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('d-none');
        }
    });
    
});
```

just use this code. This is for all div tags in html. if you want just for .column classed div's use `$('div.column')`

Comment: Imho, the OP should show some effort before we answer, or SO will just be a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
<input class="form-input" id="filter" type="text" placeholder="filter"/>
    <?php
    $a = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    
    foreach ($a as $item) {
        echo '<div class="column col-3" id="' . $item . '" >' . $item . '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#filter").keypress(function (e) {
                const val = e.target.value;
                $('div.column').each(function (ind, ele) {
                    if (ele.id.includes(val)) {
                        $(ele).hide();
                    } else {
                        $(ele).show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why should they try it? What does it do? How does it work? A good answer includes a proper and detailed explanation, not just a chunk of code. And imho, the OP should show some effort before we answer, or SO will just be a free coding service.